# How to diable MimeType?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I used

```
acceptedFiles: "image/png,image/jpeg",
```

in dropzone configuration. But it **added on canvas!** and didn't download on server:
[image]

How to hide it?

Comment: problem in your code, i suspect

Comment: What do you mean by **added on canvas** ?

Comment: png and jpeg is uploading

Comment: canvas — field, where you droping files